# how to get unique pairs of items present in the same id with SQL

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

**The initial table is like below:**

| session_id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | t-shirt |
| 1 | trousers |
| 1 | hat |
| 2 | belt |
| 2 | shoes |

I want to generate a table with all the unique pairs in the same session_id (I want to be able to do this with SQL, or more preferably SQLAlchemy Python).

**Below is the example table I want to generate from the example table above:**

| session_id | item_a | item_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t-shirt | trousers |
| 1 | t-shirt | hat |
| 1 | trousers | hat |
| 2 | belt | shoes |

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part did you get stuck on?

Comment: Add a new session_id, with only one item, and update the expected result accordingly.

Comment: @jarlh im using sqlite currently. Kind of building a flask app

Comment: @jarlh not sure what you mean on ur second comment

Comment: @matszwecja nothing so far, im not that pro in sql

Comment: Also, are you *really* sure that's what you *need* to do? Such pairs shouldn't be stored in the DB, it's very inefficient in terms of data storage.

Comment: @matszwecja what the best way to store this?

Comment: @matszwecja this is mainly used for association rule mining, i don't see any other way

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing your actual use case, but most likely calculating it in the actual app from the original table would be much better. Let's say you've got 20 items with same session id. This would become 190 pairs, so you are using more than **9.5x** more space to store the data. And it becomes even worse the more repeated session ids you get. That negatively impacts both response time and database size.

Comment: @matszwecja but i need the second table to know what session_id a certain pair comes from. As i need to retrieve more information about a certain pair from a third table using the session_id. So if i do this in the actual app then i would be doing it each time the user clicks on a pair, which will make it very slow

Comment: You should be able to do this with `grouping across session_id, title` however it's a question of IF you should rather than CAN you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a self join as the following:

```
select a.session_id,
       a.item item_a,
       b.item item_b
from table_name a join table_name b
on a.session_id = b.session_id
   and a.item > b.item
order by a.session_id, a.item
```

Note that this query will not return any row for session ids with only one item.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/t9FuqAMz)

Comment: what would you think is the best way to handle session ids with one item

Comment: You are welcome, what do you want to show in item_b column? Null, or repeat item_a value? or maybe a default value.

Comment: I want it to be Null

Comment: You may do a left join and use the count window function, check this https://dbfiddle.uk/jmPk60Tm